# Longer username in Django, when there are already users in the database

Tags: django, django-south

I am using Django 1.6 and South. There's already some data in the database. How can I migrate to a longer username field safely?

Answer (score 0):

You can use, or at least borrow the idea from: https://github.com/madssj/django-longer-username-and-email

Basically, you create a migration where you use `db.alter_column' to change the max_length property of the CharField of the contrib.auth.User model, set it as high as you need.

Then, you will need to monkeypatch the User model when django your models are loaded, you could simply do something like:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxLengthValidator

username = User._meta.get_field("username")
username.max_length = <the new length you want to use>
map(lambda v: v.limit_value: <the new length>,
    filter(lambda v: isinstance(v, MaxLengthValidator),
        username.validators)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Wtower makes sense, I did the change.